# RxKotlin collectInto() MutableList using method references

Tags: kotlin, method-reference, rx-kotlin

The following code is my attempt to convert an RxJava example into Kotlin. It's supposed to collect a bunch of `Int`'s into a `MutableList`, but I get a host of errors.

```
val all: Single<MutableList<Int>> = Observable
        .range(10, 20)
        .collectInto(::MutableList, MutableList::add)
```

The errors:

```
    Error:(113, 36) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in inline fun <T> MutableList(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): MutableList<T>
Please specify it explicitly.

Error:(113, 49) Kotlin: One type argument expected for interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E> defined in kotlin.collections

    Error:(113, 67) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public abstract fun add(element: Int): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections.MutableList
public abstract fun add(index: Int, element: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.collections.MutableList
```

If I change `ImmutableList::add` to `ImmutableList<Int>::add`, I get rid of the type argument expected error, which is replaced with:

```
Error:(113, 22) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun <U : Any!> collectInto(initialValue: U!, collector: ((U!, Int!) -> Unit)!): Single<U!>!
        cannot be applied to
        (<unknown>,<unknown>)
```

This is a straight copy of the following in Java:

```
Observable<List<Integer>> all = Observable
    .range(10, 20)
    .collect(ArrayList::new, List::add);
```

I understand that the first error is telling me it's either inferring the incorrect type and I need to be more explicit (where?), but I thought that `::MutableList` would be the equivalent of `() -> MutableList<Int>`. The third error is telling me that it can't call any of the `add()` methods with the arguments, but again, I thought that `MutableList::add` is equivalent to `{ list, value -> list.add(value) }`. The fourth error tells me it can't figure out the types being applied to the `collector`.

If I use a lambda expression instead, there are no errors:

```
val all: Single<MutableList<Int>> = Observable
        .range(10, 20)
        .collectInto(mutableListOf(), { list, value -> list.add(value) })

all.subscribe { x -> println(x) }
```

I'd appreciate some comments on what I'm doing wrong with the method references, as there's clearly something I've misunderstood (looking through the [Kotlin Language Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11), I'm wondering if it's even a language feature at this time?). Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that you don't get the same error with lambdas? because I get it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, you try to apply the method signature of `collect` to the one from `collectInto`.

This can never work, since `collect` expects a `Func0<R>` and a  `Action2<R, ? super T>` and `collectInto` expects a *real object* and a `BiConsumer<U, T>`.
A constructor *reference* can't work for `collectInto` - you need a real object (e.g. your `mutableListOf()` call)

The second problem is that Kotlin is expecting a `BiConsumer` object and not a function. I'm not quite sure why. Apparently Kotlin can't handle multiple generics for lambdas and function reference from SAM-Interfaces.

You therefore need to pass an instance of `BiConsumer` and not just a function.
That's also why I asked in the comment whether you're sure about the error message:

```
range(10, 20).collectInto(mutableListOf(), { l, i ->  l.add(i) })
```

will give me an error, while

```
range(10, 20).collectInto(mutableListOf(), BiConsumer { l, i ->  l.add(i) })
```

won't.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With a bit of reading, I came to a similar conclusion, although perhaps in not such technical terms! I have no errors; what version of Kotlin are you using? I have 1.1.2-5.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/AshleyByeUK/rxkotlin/blob/6f9bb30c7b1da970c6edb4b11527c29208609056/src/main/kotlin/uk/ashleybye/rxkotlin/operatorstransformations/AdvancedOperators.kt#L107-L130) my full implementation of this example.

Comment: @amb85 I'm also using 1.1.2-5  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: who knows?! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯